# Derived Method in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Hi Any idea how to write this expression

`var splitted = dummyString.Split(new string[]{"&#10;"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(splitted[splitted.Length-1]);`

**In SSIS Package**

Comment: why dont you give a sample from input and output? so easier to get what you wanna do

Comment: SSIS has a `Script Task` component that you can use to run C# or VB code. If you really wanted to, you could put your code into a `Script Task`. However, there may be a better way to do what you're trying to do, if you explain what problem you're trying to solve. Sample data and expected output would also be very helpful.